# Webpack file-loader sets base64 src

Tags: html, vue.js, webpack, webpack-file-loader

File-Loader is not working properly for me, images are not showing up. My images are correctly placed in the dist/static/assets folder. So no issues on that.

This is my config:

```
test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
    use: [
      {
        loader: 'file-loader?hash=sha512&digest=hex&name=[hash].[ext]',
        options: {
          context: 'src',
          name: '[name].[ext]',
          publicPath : 'static/assets',
          outputPath : 'static/assets'

        }
      }
    ]
```

But the images in my source are converted to base64? And they don't work.

`<img role="presentation" src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,bW9kdWxlLmV4cG9ydHMgPSAic3RhdGljL2Fzc2V0cy90d2l0dGVyLWljb24uc3ZnIjs=">`

While the image holds its original name in the /dist/static/assets folder. How can I get the images working with the file loader?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?